# What do I need to use an Xbox One controller on PC?

Tags: pc, controllers, xbox-one

What do I need to get to use a Xbox One controller with a PC? Just the controller and a long micro USB cable? Can I go wireless? If not, is the Play & Charge kit completely pointless for PC users?

Answer (score 3):

It's currently only possible to use them wired through microUSB (it uses a proprietary wireless solution, and not the same one as 360). You need special drivers, which will either be distributed over Windows Update or you can snag them directly from [Major Nelson's official site.](http://majornelson.com/2014/06/05/pc-drivers-for-the-xbox-one-controller-available-now/)